# Data file plot and over plot using AxesGrid toolkit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data file, which is something like:

```
 X   Y   Density
 0   0   2.366
 0   1   3.365
 1   0   6.325
 1   1   36.65
```

I'd like to read this kind of data and also plot it by using `matplotlib AxesGrid`.

After plotting that data, I want to over-plot (i.e. two density field in the same plot) a similar kind of data file on that plot. Can anyone give me a simple python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file the normal way using

```
f = open("yourfile.txt", "r")
f.readlines()
```

or you could use numpy

```
import numpy as np
x,y,z = np.loadtxt("yourfile.txt", skiprows=1).transpose() #skiprows to skip the headings
```

Why do you need AxesGrid? if all your files are just like the one you posted then you can plot with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(z.reshape(2,2), interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

To clear the plot

```
plt.clf()
```

Then replot whatever you want.